# MongoDB - 2 Unique keys in Single Schema not allowed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to do this in mongoose:

```
const blogPost = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, unique: true },
  slug: { type: String, unique: true },
  //...
});
```

However, I get an error:

> MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: blog.articles
>   index: slug_1 dup key: { : null }

Is this not allowed? I just want to make sure nobody creates a slug twice, and neither uses the same title twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are creating `slug` with `null` value and getting error with having multiple documents with the `null` in the `slug` field.

Use `sparse` index to eliminate the `null` values.

```
const blogPost = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, unique: true, sparse: true },
  slug: { type: String, unique: true, sparse: true },
  //...
});
```

Comment: oh might this be because I added the slug value to the schema, after I had already saved a few blogPosts in my db which do not have this value at all?

Comment: @R.Kohlisch Remove all the documents and try again -:)